# Merge two columns, prioritizing values from right-most column

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a dataset like this:

```
a      b
dog    <NA>
mouse  <NA>
chad   cat
bird   <NA>
```

I'd like a merge these columns and resolve conflicts like so

```
a      
dog    
mouse  
cat   
bird
```

So it overrides the values in column `a` if there's a value present in column `b`. If there's an NA in column `b`, ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the coalesce function from dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)

df_example %>%
  mutate(c = coalesce(b,a))
```

Comment: Man, I'm dumb. I was aware of coalesce, but just didn't think to reverse the order. Thanks

Comment: No problem we all forget how stuff works, gl!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
ifelse(is.na(df$b),df$a,df$b)
```